# "Request to run job dbxxxxx refused" error in merge replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm doing merge replication whole of my database  but when I  create the subscription I encounter this error:

**SQLServerAgent Error: Request to run job DBXX-XX--bazresiostani2-2 (from User sa) refused because the job is already running from a request by User sa.
Changed database context to 'DBXXX'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22022)**

but I don't have this error when creating replication with some tables in database.
The publication database is 2008R2 and the subscriber database is 2005

Comment: Is there already a job with that name on the distributor?  Was the database already setup for replication before?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting SQL Server Agent service.

(per [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatawarehousing/thread/086b3ccb-239f-4c1a-9113-7ec7bce1b212))